# og:image - how to make it larger, on a fb shared box?

Tags: facebook

According to the facebook documentation here:
(Point 2)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist/

It is stated that if the image is bigger then a certain measure, instead of a thumbnail, we will have that image on top, with the full width of that **shared box**.

1) On fb debugger I get no errors, nor warnings. (using fbrefresh).

2) The image is a regular jpg file, nothing fancy.

3) The image dimensions are: 
**1906x1104**

Is there something else we should look at, in order to understand why does this image still appears as a small side thumbnail?

Something to do with the aspect ratio?

Please advice, if you happen to have experience on those situations.

ty

Answer (score 0):

If the larger image has the same name as a previous smaller image, try renaming it. Facebook doesn't update its image cache when using fbrefresh.

Comment: Tkyou for your reply. At first I had no image displayed, due to cache issues. But since the image was properly read by fb, it has been always of this size, never smaller. :( - hence, I believe other conditions may be being applied, that we may not be aware of.